# div collection prints only one value

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, watin

Hi i am trying to print the div collection.while printing the div collection i am getting the first value only.here is my program.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WatiN.Core;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using FileHelpers;
using RealEstate.Core;
using ConsoleApplication3;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Browser bi;
            bi = new IE(@"https://www.proptiger.com/gurgaon/sector-37c/ild-grand-501804");
            string BHK_Collection = string.Empty;
            string Total_Units_details = string.Empty;
            DivCollection collection = bi.Divs.Filter(Find.ByClass("projImgContBoxInfo ng-scope"));

             foreach (var Span in collection)
             {
                 if (Span.OuterText.Contains("Basic information"))
                 {
                     BHK_Collection = Span.OuterText.Replace("  Request a site visit", "").Replace("Basic information", "").Replace("This configuration is available from builder", "").Replace("2D 3D Video Tour", "").Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("Bedroom(s)", "Bedroom(s);").Replace("Bath(s)", "Bath(s);").Replace("Balconie(s)", "Balconie(s);").Replace("Price On Request", "Price On Request;").Replace("Servant Room", "Servant Room;").Replace("sq ft", "sq ft;").Replace("Cr*", "Cr;").Replace("Request a floor plan", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("− Builder Price", "").Replace("Lacs*", "Lacs;").TrimStart();
                     Total_Units_details = string.Join(" ", BHK_Collection.Split('\r', '\n')).Replace("    ", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ").TrimStart();
                 }
             }

             Console.WriteLine(Total_Units_details);            
         }
     }
 }
```

the actual output is

```
2BHK+2T - 1,280 sq ft ;66.6 Lacs;5,200 / sq ft;2 Bedroom(s);2 Bath(s);4   Balconie(s);EMI -  54,995
2BHK+2T - 1,310 sq ft ; 68.1 Lacs;5,200 / sq ft;2 Bedroom(s);2 Bath(s);3 Balconie(s);EMI -  56,233
3BHK+3T – 1,790 sq ft; 88.6 Lacs;4,950 / sq ft; 3 Bedrooms;3 Baths; 3 Balconies;EMI - 74,400
3BHK+3T – 1,820 sq ft; 90.1 Lacs;4,950 / sq ft; 3 Bedrooms;3 Baths;;EMI - 74,400
3BHK+4T Study – 2,289 sq ft; 1.66 Cr;7,250 / sq ft; 3 Bedrooms;4 Baths; 5 Balconies;EMI - 1,40,377
```

but my program prints one value only.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the code is formatted so that we can read it easily, you may get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending to `Total_Units_details` instead you are assigning a new value at every iteration in the loop.

You can use :

```
foreach (var Span in collection)
{
    if (Span.OuterText.Contains("Basic information"))
    {
        BHK_Collection = Span.OuterText.Replace("  Request a site visit", "").Replace("Basic information", "").Replace("This configuration is available from builder", "").Replace("2D 3D Video Tour", "").Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("Bedroom(s)", "Bedroom(s);").Replace("Bath(s)", "Bath(s);").Replace("Balconie(s)", "Balconie(s);").Replace("Price On Request", "Price On Request;").Replace("Servant Room", "Servant Room;").Replace("sq ft", "sq ft;").Replace("Cr*", "Cr;").Replace("Request a floor plan", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("− Builder Price", "").Replace("Lacs*", "Lacs;").TrimStart();
        //CHANGE HERE :
        Total_Units_details = Total_Units_details + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(" ", BHK_Collection.Split('\r', '\n')).Replace("    ", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ").TrimStart();

    }
}
```

(String concatenation) : "first line" + Environment.NewLine + "second line";

*Also try to lookup the class `StringBuilder` it is better than using the method above. You can append the new String to your StringBuilder in every iteration of the loop and after that append `Environment.NewLine`*

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Browser bi;
        bi = new IE(@"https://www.proptiger.com/gurgaon/sector-37c/ild-grand-501804");

        string BHK_Collection = string.Empty;

        string Total_Units_details = string.Empty;

        DivCollection collection = bi.Divs.Filter(Find.ByClass("projImgContBoxInfo ng-scope"));

        foreach (var Span in collection)
        {
            if (Span.OuterText.Contains("Basic information"))
            {
                BHK_Collection = Span.OuterText.Replace("  Request a site visit", "").Replace("Basic information", "").Replace("This configuration is available from builder", "").Replace("2D 3D Video Tour", "").Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("Bedroom(s)", "Bedroom(s);").Replace("Bath(s)", "Bath(s);").Replace("Balconie(s)", "Balconie(s);").Replace("Price On Request", "Price On Request;").Replace("Servant Room", "Servant Room;").Replace("sq ft", "sq ft;").Replace("Cr*", "Cr;").Replace("Request a floor plan", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("− Builder Price", "").Replace("Lacs*", "Lacs;").TrimStart();
                Total_Units_details = string.Join(" ", BHK_Collection.Split('\r', '\n')).Replace("    ", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ").TrimStart();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Total_Units_details);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output each line to the console then you need to move the `Console.WriteLine` to within the `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var Span in collection)
{
    if (Span.OuterText.Contains("Basic information"))
    {
         BHK_Collection = Span.OuterText.Replace("  Request a site visit", "").Replace("Basic information", "").Replace("This configuration is available from builder", "").Replace("2D 3D Video Tour", "").Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("Bedroom(s)", "Bedroom(s);").Replace("Bath(s)", "Bath(s);").Replace("Balconie(s)", "Balconie(s);").Replace("Price On Request", "Price On Request;").Replace("Servant Room", "Servant Room;").Replace("sq ft", "sq ft;").Replace("Cr*", "Cr;").Replace("Request a floor plan", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("− Builder Price", "").Replace("Lacs*", "Lacs;").TrimStart();
         Total_Units_details = string.Join(" ", BHK_Collection.Split('\r', '\n')).Replace("    ", "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ").TrimStart();
         Console.WriteLine(Total_Units_details);
    }
}
```